# Add a child li dynamicaly to ul with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add a custum `li` to an `ol` with jquery event,
this is my code

```
success: function(data) {
            if (data != ''){
                $ulSub = $("#firstList");
                                $("#Pushtype_destinationList").val(crit1);
                $.each(data.dataa, function (i,item) {
           $str="";

                    for(var key in item){ if(key != 'id'){$str+= item[key]} }
                    $ulSub.append( '<li class="ui-widget-content " id="'+item.id +'" >' +$str+'</li>');

                });
            }
        }
```

and my code in html given as follow

```
 <ol class="selected" id="firstList">
                <li class="ui-widget-content ">text 1</li>
                <li class="ui-widget-content ">text 2</li>

            </ol>
```

and the function jquery that add an element li from the first ol to the second ol is as

```
    jQuery('ol#firstList li').click(function() {

       $(this).toggleClass('selected');

      $('#result').html($('#firstList .selected').clone())

   });
```

until now every thing work great, but when I clic on a new element add dynamically by using this function

```
 ( `for(var key in item){ if(key != 'id'){$str+= item[key]} }
                            $ulSub.append( '<li class="ui-widget-content " id="'+item.id +'" >' +$str+'</li>');

                        });)
```

this element cannot be added to the second `<ol id="result>`

[image]

as you see here, when the element text1 and text2 are added when i clic on them, but the other element which are added dynamically not

any help please

Comment: You need to delegate event  https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens because you only assign your event handler to items already existing in the DOM by the time your event handler assignment code runs.

Try:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', 'ol#firstList li', function() {
     $(this).toggleClass('selected');
     $('#result').html($('#firstList .selected').clone())
});
```

Look jQuery documentation for '.on' for further details.

Answer (score 0):

clear html before each loop like

```
$ulSub.html('');
```

PUT fellow code

```
success: function(data) {
            if (data != ''){
                $ulSub = $("#firstList");
                $("#Pushtype_destinationList").val(crit1);
                $ulSub.html('');
                $.each(data.dataa, function (i,item) {
                $str="";
                for(var key in item){ if(key != 'id'){$str+= item[key]} }
                    $ulSub.append( '<li class="ui-widget-content " id="'+item.id +'" >' +$str+'</li>');

                });
            }
        }
```